# Different link color on different html pages using the same css doc

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, styles

I'm fairly new to programming, so I apologize for what is, I'm sure, a relatively simple question.

I'm looking for an efficient way to make the link color within the `<a>` tags of each html page different (i.e. one page will have green links, while another will have blue links) without having to add `class="green"` or `class="blue"` to every single `<a>` tag.

I understand that I could have separate css documents for each page, but I'd like to keep the whole site on one css page, so I don't have to update each style sheet separately when I want to make overarching changes.

Is there a way of defining the style rules in the `<a>` tags in relation to the class of a higher tag? For example, would it be possible to say

```
<body>
<div class="page1content">
<p>text here 
<a href="someurl.com"> link here </a> 
more text 
<a href="secondurl.com"> second link</p> 
</div>

<div class="footer">
<p>even more text
<a href="thirdurl.com"></a></p>
</div>
</body>
```

and then define the first two `<a>` tags (without affecting the third `<a>` tag) in relation to the `<div class="page1content">`? I'd then replace that with `<div class="page2">`, `<div class="page3">`, etc. for each page.

The only other thing I could think of was to try using JavaScript, which I'm not too familiar.
I tried inserting

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myObj = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
myObj.style.color="green";
</script>
```

into a given page, hoping that it would make the text color within all the `<a>` tags on that page green, but it didn't seem to work.

By way of comparison, I also tested my JavaScript by changing the "a" to a "p" as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myObj = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
myObj.style.color="green";
</script>
```

in the hope that this would turn all my `<p>` text green, but that didn't work either, so clearly I miscoded the JavaScript, for starters.

Any thoughts on how to alter multiple `<a>` tags on a given page at once (without putting a class inside the tag) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each body element an ID, then select the descendent anchor tag element in your CSS:

```
body#myBody1 a {color: red;}

body#myBody2 a {color: blue;}
```

Comment: In a bit more complicated CSS styling page structure this will fail IINW

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning html/css on my own, and I didn't understand that you had to put the element after the id/class selector to reference an id/class from a higher element. It makes sense (and works) now! Thanks to @rishikesh as well for the same answer. I feel a little silly given how simple the answer is...

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ilodur/1/edit)**</kbd>

Add an ID to your BODY element like:

```
<body id="page1">
```

JavaScript:

```
var colorStyles = {
  "page1":"fuchsia",
  "page2":"green",
  "page3":"orange"
};

// DETECT body ID (AKA pageName)
var pageName = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].id;

// COLLECT YOUR ANCHOR ELEMENTS
var A_obj = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

// LOOP ANCHOR ELEMENTS TO ADD .style.color
for(var i=0; i<A_obj.length; i++) {
    A_obj[i].style.color = colorStyles[ pageName ];
}
```

---

**If you're unable due to your template structure to add an ID to your `body`**, than just add a dummy element inside your pages like:

```
<div id="page" name="page1" style="display:none;"></div>
```

and change just this JS line:

```
var pageName = document.getElementById("page").getAttribute('name');
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ilodur/2/edit)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense, though it turns out to be doable without JavaScript. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question. May be following is your answer. If there is any mistakes please correct it.

```
<style type="text/css">
   .page1content a
{
color:red;
}
      .footer a
{
color:pink;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="page1content">
<p>text here 
<a href="someurl.com"> link here </a> 
more text 
<a href="secondurl.com"> second link</p> 
</div>

<div class="footer">
<p>even more text
<a href="thirdurl.com"></a></p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the means for doing this in pure HTML and CSS. No need for Javascript.

You want to target content inside the two classes in other words. And you also forgot to close your p and a tag.

## Example:

### CSS

```
#content1 p {
    color: green;
}

#content1 a {
    color: yellow;
}

#content2 p {
    color: blue;
}

#content2 a {
    color: red;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="content1">
    <p>Text here <a href="someurl.com">and link here,</a> more text <a href="secondurl.com"> second link</a></p>
</div>

<div id="content2">
    <p>Text here <a href="someurl.com">and link here,</a> more text <a href="secondurl.com"> second link</a></p>
</div>
```

## Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/vA369/2/

Answer (score 0):

Let us take your code as an example.

1. The tag `<a></a>` has its default color.If you want `<a></a>` has
   the same color with the upper `<p></p>`

   `<p>text here  <a href="someurl.com"> link here </a>  more text  <a
   href="secondurl.com"> second link</p>`

   You must resert CSS. `<style>a{color:inherit}</style>`
2. You can do it through changing CSS.

   `<style>.page1content a {color:red}</style>`

   It means the color of tag 'a' in the div which class is
   'page1content'
3. You can also do it through javascript as you mentioned.

   But you've made a mistake.`getElementsByTagName` will return a
   array, not just one.The array contains all the result.

   For example,You can get the first `<p>...</p` with
   `document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]`